# How can I pass a function into a tkinter class if it's in a separate .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use this "search_pressed()" function in my "main.py" file as a command passed into my Tk class in a separate file called "main_window.py"

But when I try to run the code, it says:

```
NameError: name 'tkinter_menu' is not defined
```

Here is the code from my main.py file:

```
from main_window import MainMenu

def search_pressed():
    tk_data = tkinter_menu.get_tk_entries()
    print(tk_data)

tkinter_menu = MainMenu(search_pressed)
```

And here is the code from my main_window.py file:

```
from tkinter import *

class MainMenu(Tk):
    def __init__(self, search_function):
        super().__init__()
        # Entry:
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2.5, columnspan=2)

        # Search Button
        self.search_button = Button(master=self, width=20, text="Search", bg="#53A1DB", command=search_function)
        self.search_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

        self.mainloop()

    def get_tk_entries(self):
        tk_entry = self.entry.get()

        tk_data = {
            "tk entry": tk_entry,
        }
        return tk_data
```

Comment: The code you posted should raise any error. Are you sure that `tkinter_menu = MainMenu(...)` is the global scope?

Comment: All of my code is posted here. Sorry, I'm pretty new to python, but what it seems like you are asking is if tkinter_menu is the correct var name?

Comment: Now I see the problem. You call `self.mainloop()` which means that the `MainMenu(...)` call never ends. That is why the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `self.mainloop()` never stops which means that the `MainMenu(...)` is still running. That is why the variable `tkinter_menu` is undefined.

To fix your problem:

- remove `self.mainloop()` from `main_window.py`
- change your main script to:

```py
from main_window import MainMenu

def search_pressed():
    tk_data = tkinter_menu.get_tk_entries()
    print(tk_data)

tkinter_menu = MainMenu(search_pressed)
tkinter_menu.mainloop()
```

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFESAVER!

THANK YOU!! I've been staring at this code for the past 3 hours. No joke.

Comment: @hdevs No problem. It took me a bit of time before I realised what was going on :D.

Comment: @hdevs Yeah in other words, python evaluates right side and then assigns to left side, since the left side never ends, it does not get stored in the variable and hence the variable name is not defined. [Read here for more](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

Comment: @CoolCloud Do you want to edit my answer? My explanation is no where as good as yours.

Comment: @TheLizzard Nope. The explanation is pretty good as I understood it in my first read itself :D